# Progress bar jQuery percent counter not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a skill progress bar for my project using HTML CSS and jquery. All things working fine but the percent counter option is not working when the animation run.

I need to count the percentage from 0 to the value along with the animation bar. Please help me. Thanks.

```js
jQuery(function($){

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top_of_element = $(".work-process").offset().top;
    var bottom_of_element = $(".work-process").offset().top + $(".work-process").outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
    var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)){
        $('.project-percent').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var percent = $this.attr('percent');
    $this.css("width",percent+'%');
    $({animatedValue: 0}).animate({animatedValue: percent},{
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(){
            $this.attr('percent', Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + '%');
        },
        complete: function(){
            $this.attr('percent', Math.floor(this.animatedValue) + '%');
        }
    });
});
}
});
});
```

```css
.nb-progressbar-row {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .project{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.work-process h3 {
    margin: 30px 0px 10px;
}
.project-bar {
    height: 18px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.project-percent {
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    transition: 2s linear;
}
.project-percent::before {
    content: attr(percent);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class= " my-5 nb-progressbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container my-5 nb-progressbar-conainer">
        <div class="row nexnomic-progressbar-row">
            <div class=" col work-process">
      <h2 class="text-center my-5">SCROLL DOWN</h2>
            <div class=" pt-5 project">
            <h6>Xyzzz & ABCD</h6>
            <div class="project-bar">
            <div class="project-percent" percent="95"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
            <h6>Abcd-xyz</h6>
            <div class="project-bar">
            <div class="project-percent" percent="80"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project">
            <h6>ABCDYZX</h6>
            <div class="project-bar">
            <div class="project-percent" percent="75"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```